# Confusion in static methods in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have a website. And I'm making some ajax calls to `static webmethods` wrote in the codebehind. Will it create any problem if more number of users simultaneously loads the website. Being static, there will not create multiple instances of that metod. So will it overwrite the previous user's data if another call came to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, static methods work well in a multi-threaded environment, as long as there are no static class fields that maintain state of the data. Even with those, it is possible to write working code but then thread-safe access to such fields is at the hands of the programmer. Variables local to the method belong to the thread that calls the method.

There are no "instances of methods" - static or otherwise.

Comment: so you are saying that if i use static methods, it should wrapped in static classes.  right?

Comment: No, I am not saying this. Static methods do not have access to the non-static fields of the class - to access such fields, an instance of the class has to be created.